# How to dynamically change fxFlex value in Angular5 on a static screen-size?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-flex-layout

I have two columns as below and I wanted to dynamically swap/change fxFlex value onClick of a button. I know that if you resize screen, fxFlex.md/lg etc will kick-in which I was able to accomplish. But am trying to understand how to change the fxFlex values on a static screen-size on some event like button-click.

```
<div flexLayout="row">
  <div fxFlex="fxFlexForCol1" style="background-color: green">
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="swapViewableArea()">Click to enlarge view {{fxFlexForCol1}}</button>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="fxFlexForCol2" style="background-color: red">
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="swapViewableArea()">Click to enlarge view {{fxFlexForCol2}}</button>
    </div>
```

```
  swapViewableArea() {
    const temp = this.fxFlexForCol1;
    this.fxFlexForCol1 = this.fxFlexForCol2;
    this.fxFlexForCol2 = temp;
  }
```

On button-click I see that fxFlexForCol1 and fxFlexForCol2 values are swapped but flexLayout doesn't reflect the same in the UI-layout

Any advise please.

Answer (score 13):

You need to bind fxFlex to your property.

Replaced fxFlex with [fxFlex]=“property”

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! It saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it! Just use curly brace!

```
<div flexLayout="row">
  <div fxFlex={{fxFlexForCol1}} style="background-color: green">
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="swapViewableArea()">Click to enlarge view {{fxFlexForCol1}}</button>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex={{fxFlexForCol2}} style="background-color: red">
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="swapViewableArea()">Click to enlarge view {{fxFlexForCol2}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work for me in Angular 6. `compiler.js:215 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'fxFlex' since it isn't a known property of 'div'` - Any solution?

Comment: "Can't bind to 'fxFlex' since it isn't..."  - import FlexLayoutModule