# Cannot read property 'setProperty' of undefined fxFlex issue with ng-container Angular 9 Flex Layout

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

```
<div [fxLayout]="fields.layoutConfig.layoutDirection + ' wrap'" fxLayout.xs="column"
    [fxLayoutGap]="fields.layoutConfig.fxLayoutGap">

    <ng-container [fxFlex]="50" *ngFor="let field of fields.componentConfig;" reactiveField [field]="field" [group]="form">
    </ng-container>

</div>
```

Trying to use the [fxFlex]="50" inside the container getting an error `Cannot read property 'setProperty' of undefined`

[image]

Some of the issues https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/1046
https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/381

Answer (score 4):

you shouldn't use property binding for `fxLayout` and `fxLayoutGap`.

Comment: I have to use property binding because fxLayout and fxLayoutGap are dynamic values they are not static, fxFlex is also a dynamic value but to ask the question I put it as a static value

Comment: Reference -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602576/how-to-dynamically-change-fxflex-value-in-angular5-on-a-static-screen-size

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with

```
 <ng-container fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="right">
```

by changing `<ng-container>` into a `<div>` the error was gone...

Answer (score 0):

Bind the container inside the `<div>`

```
<div [fxLayout]="fields.layoutConfig.fxLayout + ' wrap'" fxLayout.xs="column"
    [fxLayoutGap]="fields.layoutConfig.fxLayoutGap"
    [fxLayoutAlign]="fields.layoutConfig.fxLayoutAlignHorizontal + ' ' + fields.layoutConfig.fxLayoutAlignVertical">
    <div [fxFlex]="fields.layoutConfig.fxFlex" *ngFor="let field of fields.componentConfig;">
        <ng-container reactiveField [field]="field" [group]="form"></ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```